# Error rendering maven report : Cant generate allure report data

Tags: maven, protractor

While running '"mvn site -Dallure.results_pattern=allure-results" in cmd prompt, im getting a build failure :

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:si
ault-site) on project protractor-allure-plugin-generate-html: Error durin
generation: Error rendering Maven report: Can't generate allure report da
a.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xm
ValidationEventLocator
   at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.converters.DefaultTestCaseConverter.<
nknown Source)
   while locating ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.converters.DefaultTestCas
ter
   while locating ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.converters.TestCaseConver

```
 for field at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.con
```

Unknown Source)

Below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ru.yandex.allure</groupId>
<artifactId>protractor-allure-plugin-generate-html</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <allure.version>1.4.15</allure.version>
    <allure.maven.version>2.2</allure.maven.version>
    <!-- Relative to the dir you're running from -->
    <allure.results_pattern>allure-results</allure.results_pattern>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-report-face</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>target/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>2299</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsPattern>${allure.results_pattern}</resultsPattern>
                <!--<reportVersion>1.4.15</reportVersion>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```